# What software should I use to design a poster of IOT?

Tags: print-design

I want to design my own poster as shown in attached image. Which will mainly consist various IOT devices and village objects. Does anyone knows which software is used for designing such images?[image: Sample Image]

---

Hey Guyz finally made this design using Adobe Illustrator.
Thanks alot for your suggestions.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Any vector graphics software will do nicely here is a partial list:

- Adobe Illustrator
- Bohemian Coding Sketch
- Corel Draw
- Inkscape
- Xara Designer Pro

Although you may want to use a more complicated workflow where you draw in vector app and color in raster application like Photoshop. But your mileage may vary, depends what you target, web only or print only, or both.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a vector-based drawing software like Adobe Illustrator so that you won't have any problems with the size of your work as vectors are scalable without losing any quality.

Answer (score 0):

Corel DRAW is an software professional/industrial for vector processing and more...

[image: CorelDraw x7]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Adobe Illustrator and make sure that the the document color is RGB for web or CMYK for print. It can be easily export to different format later, such as PDF, PNG, JPG, in different resolution and sizes.

Comment: Hi Mag, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you explain *why* you would use Illustrator? Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!